# How do I disable Wi-Fi roaming? (disable autoconnecting to the strongest AP)

Tags: wifi, high-sierra, airport

I can't find a way to disable Wi-Fi roaming on my Mac so I can connect to a specific AP and stay associated to it without roaming to the strongest AP. Is there any way I can do that?

My MacOS version is High Sierra 10.13.2.

I have already tried all airport JoinMode settings ( `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport prefs JoinMode`) and the "airport-bssid" tool that is available on GitHub, and both solutions didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I hope you come to find this site a useful resource! :) Can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/334484/edit) your question to clarify what you actually mean by *I have already tried all airport JoinMode settings and airport-bssid*? Those words are still open to interpretation. Also, have you had a look at setting your preferred networks (and some of the other options) at Apple > System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > Wi-Fi ?

Comment: @Monomeeth Edited my question. I have taken a look at the Wi-Fi preferences and I can't find a way to make my Mac "lock-on" to a specific access point.
I have two access points with the same SSID (same name), and my Mac roams freely between the two, but I want to keep my Mac associated to only one of the access points even if the other one has a stronger signal.

Comment: I don’t know of a way, but can you shed some light on what problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @samh My university has two access points for a network, and one of the services I need to access can only be reached if you are connected to a specific AP, and that AP is further away from my classroom than the one that's inside my classroom. I can't just change the network because students don't have access to the network configuration and it would take months for a request to change it to be accepted.

Comment: Long story short. Not possible.

Comment: Cannot answer the question, because it has been locked, but you can disable roaming with `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.airport.opproam disabled -bool true` - this will prevent macOS from trying to scan for "better" networks, and it will stick to whatever you've got.

Answer (score -1):

It is *sort of* possible to do but the wording is not clear.

If you open System Preferences > Network and click on the WiFi icon on the left side of the Network Preferences window you will see two checkboxes below the Network Name pop-up menu. On my Mac it looks like this.

[image: WiFi Preferences]

For your situation I would select your preferred network from the Network Name pop-up menu, and check **both** checkboxes so that it will auto-join your preferred network and force your Mac to *ask* to join other ones.

That is the only way I know to even get close to the settings you need without 3rd party software.